# An attribute node cannot be created after a child of the containing element

Tags: xslt

input xml:-

```
    <request version="1" type="PrintFPDPackInput">

    <keys>
<key name="OrganUnitID" value="07" />
<key name="PSIId" value="PRINT_DETAILS" />
<key name="PSILogclProcgDT" value="20.07.2016" />
<key name="PSIVrsnNo" value="1.0" />
<key name="sysId" value="GN" />
<key name="userID" value="UKLD_ZCSAdmin1" />

<key name="order_type" value="FPDT" />
<key name="archive_ind" value="Y" />
<key name="print_only" value="N" />
<key name="case_id" value="UKL_000001240009" />

<key name="calling_app" value="FileNet" />
<key name="pol_no" value="P17102-001-001" />
<key name="prod_nme" value="DL" />
<key name="bus_func_name" value="FPDT" />

<key name="log_brnd_typ_cde" value="07" />
<key name="sys_id" value="PUL" />
<key name="transfer" value="N" />
<key name="fax_ind" value="N" />
<key name="customer_type" value="Client" />
<key name="transfer_type" value="None" />
<key name="number_illustrations" value="0" />

<key name="source_system_code" value="Pulsar" />

<key name="PSIId" value="PULSAR_DETAILS" />
<key name="PSIVrsnNo" value="1.0" />
<key name="OrganUnitID" value="AD" />
<key name="sysId" value="PUL" />
<key name="Indicator" value="0" />

    </keys>
</request>
```

$My XSLT Code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:param name="User"/>
    <xsl:param name="Password"/> -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"            
            xmlns:fpd="http://zip.uk.zurich.com/fpdservice">

    <soapenv:Header/>

            <soapenv:Body>



                <fpd:PrintFPDPackInput>

                    <xsl:element name="ZDOC">

                        <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'OrganUnitID'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="OrganUnitID"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'PSIId'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="PSIId"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'PSILogclProcgDT'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="PSILogclProcgDT"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'PSIVrsnNo'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="PSIVrsnNo"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'sysId'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="sysId"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'userID'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="userID"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>


                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'order_type'">
                             <xsl:element name="order_type">
                              <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                       </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'archive_ind'">
                            <xsl:element name="archive_ind">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'print_only'">
                            <xsl:element name="print_only">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'case_id'">
                            <xsl:element name="case_id">
                              <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each> 

                        <order_gui>

                            <data>
                            <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">

                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'calling_app'">
                                    <xsl:element name="calling_app">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'pol_no'">
                                    <xsl:element name="pol_no">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'prod_nme'">
                                    <xsl:element name="prod_nme">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'bus_func_name'">
                                    <xsl:element name="bus_func_name">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each> 
                                <wfl_evnt_type_lit />

                            <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">    
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'log_brnd_typ_cde'">
                                    <xsl:element name="log_brnd_typ_cde">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'sys_id'">
                                    <xsl:element name="sys_id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each> 
                                <task_type />

                            <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">    
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'transfer'">
                                    <xsl:element name="transfer">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'fax_ind'">
                                    <xsl:element name="fax_ind">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'customer_type'">
                                    <xsl:element name="customer_type">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'transfer_type'">
                                    <xsl:element name="transfer_type">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@name = 'number_illustrations'">
                                    <xsl:element name="number_illustrations">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each> 

                                <letter_notes />
                                <requested_documents />
                                <address_override>
                                <company_client>
                                    <customer_reference_number />
                                    <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">
                                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'source_system_code'">
                                            <xsl:element name="source_system_code">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>

                                        <name />
                                        <company_contact>
                                            <name />
                                        </company_contact>
                                </company_client>
                                <address>
                                    <line_1 />
                                    <line_2 />
                                    <line_3 />
                                    <line_4 />
                                    <postcode />
                                </address>
                                </address_override>

                            </data>
                        </order_gui>


                        <pulsar>


<xsl:element name="ZDOC">

                        <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">

                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'PSIId'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="PSIId"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'PSIVrsnNo'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="PSIVrsnNo"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'organUnitID'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="organUnitID"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'sysId'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="sysId"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        </xsl:for-each>

                        <error>
                        <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key">
                            <xsl:if test="@name = 'Indicator'">
                                <xsl:element name="Indicator">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <message />
                        </error>
</xsl:element>  


                        </pulsar>



                    </xsl:element>


                </fpd:PrintFPDPackInput>





            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

$I am getting Error: An attribute node (PSIId) cannot be created after a child of the containing element. Most recent element start tag was output at line 65 of module. Can you please help on this to resolve.

---

**EDIT1:**

Below is the expected output for my XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fpd="http://zip.uk.zurich.com/fpdservice">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fpd:PrintFPDPackInput>
         <ZDOC OrganUnitId="07" PSIId="PRINT_DETAILS" PSILogclProcgDT="20.07.2016" PSIVrsnNo="1.0" sysId="GN" userID="UKLD_ZCSAdmin1">
            <order_type>FPDT</order_type>
            <archive_ind>Y</archive_ind>
            <print_only>N</print_only>
            <case_id>UKL_000001240009</case_id>
            <order_gui>
               <data>
                  <calling_app>FileNet</calling_app>
                  <pol_no>P17102-001-001</pol_no>
                  <prod_nme>DL</prod_nme>
                  <bus_func_name>FPDT</bus_func_name>
                  <wfl_evnt_type_lit />
                  <log_brnd_typ_cde>07</log_brnd_typ_cde>
                  <sys_id>PUL</sys_id>
                  <task_type />
                  <transfer>N</transfer>
                  <fax_ind>N</fax_ind>
                  <customer_type>Client</customer_type>
                  <transfer_type>None</transfer_type>
                  <number_illustrations>0</number_illustrations>
                  <letter_notes />
                  <requested_documents />
                  <address_override>
                     <company_client>
                        <customer_reference_number />
                        <source_system_code>Pulsar</source_system_code>
                        <name />
                        <company_contact>
                           <name />
                        </company_contact>
                     </company_client>
                     <address>
                        <line_1 />
                        <line_2 />
                        <line_3 />
                        <line_4 />
                        <postcode />
                     </address>
                  </address_override>
               </data>
            </order_gui>
            <pulsar>
               <ZDOC PSIId="PULSAR_DETAILS" PSIVrsnNo="1.0" organUnitId="AD" sysId="PUL">
                  <error>
                     <Indicator>0</Indicator>
                     <message />
                  </error>
</ZDOC>
            </pulsar>
</ZDOC>
      </fpd:PrintFPDPackInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part I of question/solution**

> An attribute node (PSIId) cannot be created after a child of containing element. most receon element start tag was output at line 65 of module.

Depending on the sortorder of nodes in your input-document, the same sortorder will be used to create elements/attributes. [if no process-flow changing instructions were used]. Therefore you created a childnode [in your example `case_id`] AND after that you wanted to create an attribute for `PSIId`.

**First you have to create all attributes THEN you can create childnodes.**

---

**Part II**

Safer and improved version of your stylesheet would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:param name="User"/>
    <xsl:param name="Password"/> -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"            
            xmlns:fpd="http://zip.uk.zurich.com/fpdservice">

            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <fpd:PrintFPDPackInput>
                    <ZDOC>
                        <!-- attributes -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'OrganUnitID' or @name = 'PSILogclProcgDT' or @name = 'PSIVrsnNo' or @name = 'sysId' or @name = 'userID'] | request/keys/key[@name = 'PSIId'][1]" />
                        <!-- childs -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'order_type' or @name = 'archive_ind' or @name = 'print_only']" />

                        <order_gui>
                            <data>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'calling_app' or @name = 'pol_no' or @name = 'prod_nme' or @name = 'bus_func_name']" /> 
                                <wfl_evnt_type_lit />
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'log_brnd_typ_cde' or @name = 'sys_id']" />
                                <task_type />
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'transfer' or @name = 'fax_ind' or @name = 'customer_type' or @name = 'transfer_type' or @name = 'number_illustrations']" /> 
                                <letter_notes />
                                <requested_documents />
                                <address_override>
                                    <company_client>
                                        <customer_reference_number />
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'source_system_code']"/>
                                        <name />
                                        <company_contact>
                                            <name />
                                        </company_contact>
                                    </company_client>
                                    <address>
                                        <line_1 />
                                        <line_2 />
                                        <line_3 />
                                        <line_4 />
                                        <postcode />
                                    </address>
                                </address_override>
                            </data>
                        </order_gui>
                        <pulsar>
                            <ZDOC>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'PSIId'][2] | request/keys/key[@name = 'PSIVrsnNo' or @name = 'organUnitID']" />

                                <error>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'Indicator']" />
                                    <message />
                                </error>
                            </ZDOC> 

                        </pulsar>
                    </ZDOC>
                </fpd:PrintFPDPackInput>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="key[@name = 'OrganUnitID' or @name = 'PSIId' or @name = 'PSILogclProcgDT' or @name = 'PSIVrsnNo' or @name = 'sysId' or @name = 'userID']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="key[@name = 'order_type' or @name = 'archive_ind' or @name = 'print_only' or @name = 'calling_app' or @name = 'pol_no' or @name = 'prod_nme' or @name = 'bus_func_name' or @name = 'log_brnd_typ_cde' or @name = 'transfer' or @name = 'fax_ind' or @name = 'customer_type' or @name = 'transfer_type' or @name = 'number_illustrations' or @name = 'source_system_code' or @name = 'Indicator']">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: added position of `key @name='PSIId'` for correct result.

*please verify on your own if i matched everything like previous. but i am sure, you can complete it on your own and fix it for your needs.*

Comment: $ If you look at the PSIID above, it has different values for each. But when we run your XSLT with my input. it is updating same value for the PSIID. But we require different values at runtime. Please help on this by verifying at : http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: @Raghava see my change in answer. there are two keys with name `PSIID`, so we have to work with a position. e.g. `request/keys/key[@name = 'PSIId'][1]`