# Include tags in XSLT for every copy

Tags: xslt

Below is the input xml:-

```
<request version="1" type="PrintFPDPackInput">

    <keys>
<key name="Date" value="02/01/2010 01:00:25" />
<key name="AmtGross" value="22.33" />
<key name="AmtNet" value="17.86" />
<key name="ContribType" value="Individual" />

<key name="Date" value="01/01/2010 01:00:26" />
<key name="AmtGross" value="22.25" />
<key name="AmtNet" value="17.80" />
<key name="ContribType" value="Individual" />

<key name="Date" value="12/01/2009 01:00:27" />
<key name="AmtGross" value="22.25" />
<key name="AmtNet" value="17.80" />
<key name="ContribType" value="Individual" />


    </keys>
</request>
```

The XSLT processed :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- <xsl:param name="User"/>
    <xsl:param name="Password"/> -->

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                        xmlns:fpd="http://zip.uk.zurich.com/fpdservice">
        <soapenv:Header/>

<soapenv:Body>
<fpd:CheckFPD>

<xsl:copy>
<policy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="request/keys/key[@name = 'Date' or @name = 'AmtGross' or @name = 'AmtNet' or @name = 'ContribType']" />
</policy>
    </xsl:copy>






</fpd:CheckFPD>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="key[@name = 'Date' or @name = 'AmtGross' or @name = 'AmtNet' or @name = 'ContribType' ]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the error output I am getting as below: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:fpd="http://zip.uk.zurich.com/fpdservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fpd:CheckFPD>
         <policy>
            <Date>02/01/2010 01:00:25</Date>
            <AmtGross>22.33</AmtGross>
            <AmtNet>17.86</AmtNet>
            <ContribType>Individual</ContribType>
            <Date>01/01/2010 01:00:26</Date>
            <AmtGross>22.25</AmtGross>
            <AmtNet>17.80</AmtNet>
            <ContribType>Individual</ContribType>
            <Date>12/01/2009 01:00:27</Date>
            <AmtGross>22.25</AmtGross>
            <AmtNet>17.80</AmtNet>
            <ContribType>Individual</ContribType>
         </policy>
      </fpd:CheckFPD>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected output as below format:-

```
<ListOfPolicyReceipts>
                           <PolicyReceipts>
                              <Date>02/01/2010 01:00:25</Date>
                              <AmtGross>22.33</AmtGross>
                              <AmtNet>17.86</AmtNet>
                              <ContribType>Individual</ContribType>
                           </PolicyReceipts>
                           <PolicyReceipts>
                              <Date>01/01/2010 01:00:26</Date>
                              <AmtGross>22.25</AmtGross>
                              <AmtNet>17.80</AmtNet>
                              <ContribType>Individual</ContribType>
                           </PolicyReceipts>
                           <PolicyReceipts>
                              <Date>12/01/2009 01:00:27</Date>
                              <AmtGross>22.25</AmtGross>
                              <AmtNet>17.80</AmtNet>
                              <ContribType>Individual</ContribType>
                           </PolicyReceipts>
```

Kindly suggest process the tags PolicyReceipts is applied for every copy of data

Comment: if that's your expected output, why does your stylesheet create a SOAP envelope and header?

Comment: related [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575072/an-attribute-node-cannot-be-created-after-a-child-of-the-containing-element). this is - i would call it - a "addon"-thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see the xsd, so I assume, the tag `ListOfPolicyReceipts` will replace the tag `policy`. But i am pretty sure, you can implement the following code on the correct place in your stylesheet.

Probably you can use this one:

```
<ListOfPolicyReceipts>
    <xsl:for-each select="request/keys/key[@name = 'Date']">
        <PolicyReceipts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::key[@name = 'AmtGross'][1] | following-sibling::key[@name = 'AmtNet'][1] | following-sibling::key[@name = 'ContribType'][1]"/>
        </PolicyReceipts>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ListOfPolicyReceipts>
```

**Important:**

- all 4 elements with name `date`, `AmtGross`, `AmtNet` and `ContribType` have to be in that specific order!
- all 4 elements have to be present; if one is missing, the xslt will fail and output wrong data [probably the output is valid, but the content is wrong]

Answer (score 0):

The posted expected output can be achieved quite simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/request">
    <ListOfPolicyReceipts>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="keys/key[@name = 'Date']"/>
    </ListOfPolicyReceipts>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="key">
    <PolicyReceipts>
        <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::key[position() &lt; 4]">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </PolicyReceipts>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming the input will always list the `key` elements in groups of 4, with `<key name="Date">` being the first in its group.